# how to use wait or thread to wait till the event occurs

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, listbox

Say in winforms I have a listbox.

and I also have a thread which waits till there is some item in listbox.

Say currently the list box is empty, so the thread have to wait.

Say now there is some item in listbox the thread has to begin execution.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Show your effort and read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why does this need to be a thread? Why can't you handle an event?

Comment: which event ???? There is no ItemsChanged or ItemsAdded event in ListBox

Comment: Is there a way you can create a single methods for adding elements to the list box ? (Subclassing or custom control) From there on you could create your own event.

Comment: @BoasEnkler - right, surely there must be something that can be overridden even if no simpler way is available.

Comment: What about 'SelectedValueChanged?

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of Timers which can periodic checks the listbox items if there is some item than
start your thread and stop checking .

Answer (score 0):

You could use threads, but I think you will be better off with an event-based method for processing. The ListBox class doesn't have an event for adding items by default, but you can extend the class to make your own. Here's an example of how you would do that:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    private const int LB_ADDSTRING = 0x180;
    private const int LB_INSERTSTRING = 0x181;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == LB_ADDSTRING || m.Msg == LB_INSERTSTRING)
        {
            OnItemAdded(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public event EventHandler ItemAdded;
    protected void OnItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Once you have made this class, just use it on your form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyListBox lb = new MyListBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(lb);
        lb.ItemAdded += lb_ItemAdded;
    }

    void lb_ItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // process item here...
    }       
}
```